# How can I add a class to a block with code (development)

Tags: 7

For theming reasons I'd like to add a specific class at the "block" level to some of the blocks I'm generating with a custom module. I know there is a module [block class](http://drupal.org/project/block_class), but I would rather like to do it directly in code (there is no need to change is afterwards).

I also know of [hook_block_view_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/7), but that does not seem to allow adding or editing classes.

Is it possible to add a class with to a block from within my module code? I'm using Drupal 7.

Comment: D8 version of this question: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/181078/how-to-add-a-class-attribute-to-a-block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@flocondetoile's answer is OK, but the correct way is using [drupal_html_class()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_html_class/7).

```
function YOURMODULE_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  $variables['classes_array'][] = drupal_html_class('your-custom-class');
}
```

The function can be used from a module, or a theme.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. One extra bit of information: this example will add the class to all blocks on the page, not just the blocks of your module. If you only want to target the blocks defined for a specific module, check the module name in $variables['block']->module.

Answer (score 3):

Simply, you could use a preprocess function.

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['block_html_id'] ==  'ID-YOUR-BLOCK') {
    $vars['attributes_array']['class'][] = 'YOUR-CLASS';
  }
}
```